# Sizeof an object with/without virtual identifier

Tags: c++, class, virtual, sizeof

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class base
{
 virtual int fun(int i){int j;}
};
int main()
{   base b;
    cout<<sizeof(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 4

now :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class base
{
 int fun(int i){int j;}     //removed virtual
};
int main()
{   base b;
    cout<<sizeof(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :1

Why is there difference in both outputs??

Comment: Because of the virtual function table pointer.

Comment: You can make it a lot easier on yourself and us by just pasting your code, highlighting it, and hitting the format button or pressing ctrl-K.